# bootstrap datepicker does not show on small screens on firefox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, bootstrap-4, datepicker

For some odd reason, the datepicker does not show up on smaller screens on Firefox. I am currently using ver 78.0.2 (64-bit). When tested on Chrome, it works perfectly, on mobile sized screens and regular screens.

After returning from small screens to regular screens, the datepicker now doesn't show. It is quite Firefox specific, any solution to this?

my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Availability</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!--Screens lg and above -->
        <!--block on md screens because it looks ugly af-->
        <!--
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 p-0">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="images/banner.png" style="width:100%;max-height:300px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
-->
        <div class="row pb-3 pt-2" style="background-color:#042a3d">
            <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 text-light">
                <form class="form-inline row">
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
                        <!--js version-->
                        <p class="mb-1">Check in</p>
                        <input type="date" id="startDate" min="" style="width:100%" class="form-control" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
                        <!--js version-->
                        <p class="mb-1">Check out</p>
                        <input type="date" id="endDate" min="" style="width:100%" class="form-control" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 text-center" style="margin-top:25px">
                        <button style="width:100%" id="availSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Check Availability</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>







    <script>
        formatDate = (date) => {
            var day = date.getDate().toString();
            var month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
            var year = date.getFullYear();

            if (day.length < 2) {
                day = "0" + day;
            }
            if (month.length < 2) {
                month = "0" + month;
            }

            var formattedDate = [year, month, day].join('-');
            return formattedDate;
        }
        //onload initialization
        $(document).ready(() => {
            console.log("It's ready and loaded!");
            var today = new Date();
            var tmr = new Date();
            tmr.setDate(tmr.getDate() + 1);

            $('#startDate').val(formatDate(today));
            $('#endDate').val(formatDate(tmr));

            $('#startDate').attr('min', $('#startDate').val());
            $('#endDate').attr('min', $('#endDate').val());

            //for default screens
            $("#availSubmit").on("click", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                //initalizations
                var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
                var string_startDate = $("#startDate").val();
                var string_endDate = $("#endDate").val();


                //check date difference
                var date_startDate = new Date(string_startDate);
                var date_endDate = new Date(string_endDate);
                var diff = (date_endDate.getTime() - date_startDate.getTime()) / one_day;

                //bookings cannot be -1 or 0 days. TESTING PURPOSES
                if (diff < 1) {
                    alert("Invalid booking!");
                } else {
                    alert("Valid booking!");
                }
                //code below does get request or whatever
            });

            //onchange for start and end date
            $('#startDate').on('change', () => {
                var newEndDate = new Date($('#startDate').val());
                newEndDate.setDate(newEndDate.getDate() + 1);
                $('#endDate').attr('min', formatDate(newEndDate));
                $('#endDate').val(formatDate(newEndDate));
            });

        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution and decided to just rewrite it in jquery ui's datepicker.

Code is as below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
    <title>Availability</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!--Screens lg and above -->
        <!--block on md screens because it looks ugly af-->

        <!--
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 p-0">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="images/banner.png" style="width:100%;max-height:300px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
-->

        <div class="row pb-3 pt-2" style="background-color:#042a3d">
            <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 text-light">
                <form class="form-inline row">
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
                        <!--js version-->
                        <p class="mb-1">Check in</p>
                        <input type="text" id="startDate" style="width:100%" class="form-control" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
                        <!--js version-->
                        <p class="mb-1">Check out</p>
                        <input type="text" id="endDate" style="width:100%" class="form-control" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 text-center" style="margin-top:25px">
                        <button style="width:100%" id="availSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Check Availability</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--datepicker-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>






    <script>        
        formatDate = (date) => {
            var day = date.getDate().toString();
            var month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
            var year = date.getFullYear();

            if (day.length < 2) {
                day = "0" + day;
            }
            if (month.length < 2) {
                month = "0" + month;
            }

            var formattedDate = [day, month, year].join('/');
            return formattedDate;
        }
        //onload initialization
        $(document).ready(() => {
            console.log("It's ready and loaded!");
            var today = new Date();
            var tmr = new Date();
            tmr.setDate(tmr.getDate() + 1);

            $('#startDate').val(formatDate(today));
            $('#endDate').val(formatDate(tmr));

            $('#startDate').attr('min', $('#startDate').val());
            $('#endDate').attr('min', $('#endDate').val());



            //test Date
            $('#startDate').val(formatDate(today)).datepicker({
                dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
                minDate: today,
            });
            
            $('#endDate').val(formatDate(tmr)).datepicker({
                dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
                minDate: tmr,
            });
            
            //change methods
            $('#startDate').on('change',()=>{
                var endDate = new Date($('#startDate').datepicker('getDate'));
                $('#endDate').datepicker('option','minDate',endDate);
                endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()+1);
                
                $('#endDate').datepicker('setDate',endDate);
            })
            
            $('#availSubmit').on('click',(e)=>{
                e.preventDefault();
                //initalizations
                var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
                var string_startDate = $("#startDate").val();
                var string_endDate = $("#endDate").val();


                //check date difference
                var date_startDate = new Date(string_startDate);
                var date_endDate = new Date(string_endDate);
                var diff = (date_endDate.getTime() - date_startDate.getTime()) / one_day;

                //bookings cannot be -1 or 0 days. TESTING PURPOSES
                if (diff < 1) {
                    console.log("Invalid booking!");
                } else {
                    console.log("Valid booking!");
                }
                //code below does get request or whatever
                console.log($('#startDate').datepicker('getDate'));
                console.log($('#endDate').datepicker('getDate'));
            })

        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```